# Can I make the activation of a popup <div> do something to another <div>?

Tags: html, css, popup, pointer-events

I have a link that will show a popup  once clicked.

```
<a class="button" href="#popup1"><span id="contactspan"></span></a>
```

When the link is clicked an overlay shows up together with a popup .

DIV

```
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
        <div class="popup">
            <h2>Contact</h2>

            <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
            <div class="content">
                Stuff in popup.
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}


.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.popup .content {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

My problem is that when the popup is visible, I can still click through the overlay and hit other links in my div container.
Is there a way to set "pointer-events: none;" to be applied to div id="container" as long as my popup is visible?

Comment: Use event.stopPropagation() by clicking on overlay.
And add z-index: 9999999 to overlay.

Comment: @AndreiTodorut - using a value of "*9999999*" can often create more problems than it resolves. Maintaining proper order of `z-index` makes your code more maintainable and less of a headache. Especially when a value of `2` might very well suffice.

Comment: yes, i know it . But i write a big value because is need to be the bigest z-index from the whole site. So 99999 is the bigest value of z-index. If the bigest z-index from your site is 1 the overlay z-index should be bigger than 1. This is what i want to mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called event bubbling, see

[What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

You need to use:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

In your JavaScript at the top of your event handler.